# Preserving HTML entities with libxml

Tags: html-entities, libxml2

I'm writing a method to parse an HTML string, query and obtain some nodes and then output the HTML for these nodes.

I'm using **libxml**, and have managed to load and parse the input HTML, and output the HTML string for the nodes that I want, except that I want any HTML entities preserved, and libxml seems to convert these into their associated UTF-8 characters.

Here's what I've got so far (the code is part of an Objective-C project):

```
NSString *HTMLString = ...
NSData *documentData = [HTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Create the document
xmlDocPtr doc = htmlReadMemory([documentData bytes],
                               [documentData length],
                               "",
                               NULL,
                               HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR);

//Get the node I want to output
xmlNodePtr node = ...

//Create the node buffer and fill it with the node content
xmlBufferPtr nodeBuffer = xmlBufferCreate();
htmlNodeDump(nodeBuffer, doc, node);

...
```

This dumps the HTML content of the node fine, except that character entities are converted to the UTF-8 characters – the only entities that exist in the input HTML are quotation marks such as `&rsquo;` and `&lsquo;`, which I want preserved when I write out the node's HTML content.

I've looked through the libxml docs relating to HTML parsing and the HTML tree functions and I can't seem to find any information about HTML entities. I'm also not sure whether this is something which is done during parsing or output. I did try to simply output the content of the node using `xmlNodeGetContent()` and the entities had also been replaced by the corresponding UTF8 characters, which makes me suspect that it's a parsing issue, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem is that libxml works internally with UTF-8 (explained in  [Encodings Support](http://xmlsoft.org/encoding.html) on xmlsoft), which will convert all HTML character entities to UTF-8 characters, and so when outputting HTML will leave these as converted UTF-8 characters.

The solution is also presented in the encoding section on xmlsoft, under 'Default Supported Encodings':

> libxml2 has a set of default converters for the following encodings (located in encoding.c):
>
> 1. UTF-8 is supported by default (null handlers)
> 2. UTF-16, both little and big endian
> 3. ISO-Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) covering most western languages
> 4. ASCII, useful mostly for saving
> 5. **HTML, a specific handler for the conversion of UTF-8 to ASCII with HTML predefined entities like &copy; for the Copyright sign.**

It also recommends to use the conversion functions 'like `UTF8Toisolat1`' to convert values returned from the libxml functions to another encoding.

The solution is to convert HTML output with the [`UTF8ToHtml()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html#UTF8ToHtml) function which will replace non-ASCII characters with their relevant HTML entities (such as `&rsquo;` or `&lsquo;`). This seems to leave HTML tag `<` and `>` characters untouched, unlike when I tried with `htmlEncodeEntities()`, which replaces them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

The one thing I didn't solve when using `UTF8ToHtml()` was how to determine how much memory to allocate for the output buffer, since replacing single characters with entities will increase the length of the HTML string, so you can't just use the input HTML's length. I simply allocated twice the size of the input buffer (which I imagine should be enough for all my use-cases) and then used the actual length used (returned through a pointer parameter in `UTF8ToHtml()`), but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this.